# simple input of diacritical marks, and superscripts

Tags: input, maxima, wxmaxima

There are times when you need to input modified variables with diacritical marks, or superscripts.

Seems like declare_index_properties allows doing it at the stage of display print.
But it is neither simple, nor very useful in formulas.

is there a simple way of adding hats, umlauts, and ', "strokes on top of a symbol, making it distinguishable from the symbol without such mark both to interpreter and to human eye?

Answer (score 2):

Maxima doesn't have a notion of declaring a symbol to have diacritical marks or other combining marks on it. However, Maxima allows Unicode characters in symbol names if the underlying Lisp implementation allows Unicode; almost all of them allow Unicode. GCL is the only Lisp implementation, so far as I know, which doesn't handle Unicode correctly.

WxMaxima appears to allow Unicode characters to be input. At least, it worked that way when I tried some examples. Command-line Maxima allows Unicode if the terminal it is running in allows Unicode.

I think any Unicode character should be OK in a string. For symbols, any character which passes ALPHA-CHAR-P (a build-in Lisp function) can be part of a symbol name. Also, any character which is declared to be alphabetic (via `declare("x", alphabetic)` where `x` is the character in question) can be part of a symbol name.

I think wxMaxima has some capability to allow the user to select characters with diacritical marks from a menu; I haven't tried it. When I want to use Unicode characters, I end up just pasting them from a web page or something. I have used https://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/UTF-8-demo.html as a source of characters in the past.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked via setting the diacritical mark between brackets and double quotes:
First the declaration of index properties seems still necessary, otherwise the diacritical mark will simply appear as a subscript. E.g. if I want to have A' instead of A:

```
declare_index_properties (A, [postsuperscript])$
A["'"];
```

A could have other indices, for example:

```
declare_index_properties (A, [postsubscript,postsubscript,postsuperscript])$
A[g,u,"'"];
```

(for more fancy stuff see the help for declare_index_properties).

However, I didn't find a way to add the mark above a variable.